# JdbcTemplate not getting autowired for H2 database in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using H2 db and using JdbcTemplate to connect to it but JdbcTemplate is not getting autowired, please find below my code -

**Pom.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.anmol</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoAppDb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DemoApp-1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**DemoApp1Application.java -**

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApp1Application {

    @Autowired
    StudentDao repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApp1Application.class, args);     
    }   

}
```

**StudentController.java**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.model.Student;
import com.example.demo.service.StudentService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public Student test(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        return studentService.getUser(id);
    }
}
```

**StudentService.java -**

```
package com.example.demo.service;
import com.example.demo.StudentDao;
import com.example.demo.model.Student;

public class StudentService {

    StudentDao dao = new StudentDao();

    public Student getUser(int id) {
        return dao.getUser(id);
    }

}
```

**StudentDao.java -**

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.demo.model.Student;

@Repository
public class StudentDao {


    DataSource dtaSrc = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public Student getUser(int id) {
        System.out.println("select * from student where id="+id);
        Student s = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select * from student where id="+id, new Object[] {id}, new StudentmMapper());
        return s;
    }
}
```

**Student.java -**

```
package com.example.demo.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Student(int id, String name, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Student() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }

}
```

Please let me know what is going wrong and why spring boot is not able to autowired JdbcTemplate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a constructor for  JdbcTemplate and try.

Comment: You're not using a Spring-managed bean for `StudentDao`. Check the duplicates for more information (the second duplicate covers exactly the same problem).

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b, it worked after I created Spring-managed bean for StudentDao